# Python Selenium in not writing '@'. INstead filling with other code

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using find element by id with python.

This is the code

```
driver.find_element_by_id("fromname").send_keys("abc@gmail.com")
```

the result I've got (inside the form field):

```
abcdriver.find_element_by_id("fromname").send_keys("abc@gmail.com")gmail.com
```

So as you can see selenium is replacing the '@' sign with the whole previous command..
I can't figure it out. Iw seems everyone is okay with sendkey('foo@foo.com')...

I've downloaded this chromdriver today (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=87.0.4280.20/)

Comment: that looks like a selenium issue to me, what version are you using? Check with `selenium.__version__`

Comment: Did you try escaping the @ sign with \?

Comment: The selenium version is: 3.141.0
If I write send_keys("abc\@gmail.com") it is replacing the \@ with the current clipboard.